# How do I install pyjamas?

Tags: software-installation

When Ubuntu 10.4 was in alpha stage, there was pyjamas package, which didn't work. I posted a bug on launchpad and the only resolution, was removing this package altogether.

Does anyone know, how to easily install pyjamas on Ubuntu 10.4? I tried downloading debs from debian repositories, but there were some broken dependencies.

Comment: ¿Pyjamas or Pyjamas-desktop?.

I've been using pyjamas on Ubuntu for a long time without problems. I just untared the official package and make a custom build script in my program that references the pyjamas location.

Pyjamas-desktop is quite another history...

Comment: Can you add a reference to the LP bug, i.e. link it from your question?

Comment: I mean both pyjamas and pyjamas-desktop. I have problem with the second, as I would like to be able to debug code in python, rather than in js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pyjamas package is available for Lucid from [this ppa](https://launchpad.net/~fabricesp/+archive/ppa). Although there is no pyjamas-desktop package :/ To add the ppa and install you can do

#### GUI Method

Open the Ubuntu Software Center, choose the "Edit" menu and select "Software Sources ...". Select the "Other Software" tab in the dialog box and click on the "Add ..." button. Then enter the text `"ppa:fabricesp/ppa"` and click "Add Source". Then click "Close" and wait for the update to finish. Then you should be able to use the search box to find pyjamas and install it.

#### Command Line Method

```
$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:fabricesp/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install pyjamas
```

Comment: hmm i was wondering if(pyjs == pyjamas)

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://pyjs.org/wiki/pyjamasubuntu/) may be useful.

Comment: This is a source-based installation, which will work properly, but installing via some .deb will provide better maintainability.

Answer (score 2):

You could try installing it from Maverick or Debian unstable/testing.

See https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pyjamas - which contains links to the .deb files, which you can try using for a manual installation (e.g. via `dpkg -i path/to.deb`).

Comment: I have installed all debs from here, but still when I try to run `import pyjamas` I get an ImportError.